# How to access content of NSMutable array from another class?

Tags: objective-c

I have a FirstViewControlloller in which I have a start and stop button. When start is pressed pictures are taken by using AVCaptureSession until stop button is pressed. These pictures are processed and information (The R-value component of RGB) from each picture is stored in an NSMutableArray called Yaxis.

Added to this View I have a ContainerView. In this view I want to continously display a graph of the information in my Yaxis-array. The problem is to reach this information.

Some parts of my code follow here:

FirstViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *Yaxis;
```

FirstViewController.m

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad{ 
     Yaxis=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [super viewDidLoad];
     }
```

At another place in the code objects are continuously added to "Yaxis" as pictures are taken.

```
[Yaxis addObject: RGB];
```

This works fine since I have no problem accessing the array filled with information as long as Im in FirstViewController.

To be able to use this information to update my graph I have tried to create an object of FirstViewController in my ContainerViewController and in that way reach my Yaxis array.

ContainerViewController.m

```
FirstViewController * myView=[[FirstViewController alloc] init];

myView.Yaxis
```

When I do this Yaxis is null. As I understand it the problem is that I create a new object of FirstViewController and therefore I will not be able to reach the filled array that is actually a part of another object. So how do I get connected to the object that holds my filled Yaxis array from within my ContainerViweController class?

[Access NSMutableArray from another class - Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23099908/access-nsmutablearray-from-another-class-objective-c)

I found this question that seams to adress the same problem but I did not solve my problem using the answers from there.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the array in `-(void)viewDidLoad`. But that method is not called anywhere in your second code snippet. Try putting the `Yaxis=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` line in your `init` method

Answer (score 0):

When you manually create a new FirstViewController, this is a new object unrelated to the original, and the mutable array property is initially nil.
The new VC will not magically point to the one that's displayed. Also, the VC  might get *destroyed*, and the array released.

You should separate the storage of this data in another object if it's shared between VCs.

Comment: You are definitely pinpointing the issue in you first paragraph. But I don't know how to proceed, can you provide any guidance in how to store the data?

Comment: You can try to use a singleton to store the data, assuming you don't need something fancier (database or otherwise). Also you might need to empty/nil the MutableArray manually. Read http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/